# Rename files using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to be able to rename files using PHP.

The following script checks if the new name exists. If it does (and it includes a suffix) the suffix will be incremented.

```
if(file_exists($fileName)) {
        $fileNewName= preg_replace_callback('/(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)/',                   
         function ($m) { return ++$m[0]; },
         $fileName);
 }
```

However, if the file does not include a suffix, none is added to the file.

Example:

```
filename_1.txt  becomes  filename_2.txt
however
filename.txt is not renamed.
```

Can you help me add the suffix (_1) is no suffix existed.
Example:

```
filename.txt becomes filename_1.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this (not tested):

```
if(file_exists($fileName)) {
    $fileNewName = preg_replace_callback('/(?:(?<=_)\d+)?(?=\.[^.]*$)/',                   
        function ($m) { return empty($m[0]) ? '_1' : ++$m[0]; },
         $fileName, 1);
}
```

In short, you make the beginning optional `(?:(?<=_)\d+)?` and you ensure that the dot is the last `(?=\.[^.]*$)`.
Using a ternary operator when `$m[0]` is empty, you return '_1' else the incremented value.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse.<br/>
Your suggestion does add a _1 suffix if none exists.<br/>
filename.txt    becomes   filename_1.txt<br/>
However<br/>
subsequent renaming of the file results with <br/>
filename_1.txt   becomes  filename_2_1.txt <br/>

Comment: @user3117340: indeed, you only need to set the limit parameter to 1, see the edit.